# Running docker inside a Windows 10 Hyper-V guest

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I want to ask if **anyone knows how to make Nested Virtualization work with an AMD CPU** (e.g. Ryzen)?

My workstation is running inside Hyper-V, so it is essentially a VM guest however it is important that I am able to run docker on the Windows Guest VM.

The problem is when trying to connect it throws an error saying *"nested virtualization is not supported"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to ask if anyone knows how to make Nested Virtualization work with an AMD CPU (e.g. Ryzen)?

Hyper-V doesn’t support nested virtualization on AMD processors.

One of the requirements for nested virtualization within a Hyper-V virtual machine is an Intel processor that supports VT-x.

> An Intel processor with VT-x and EPT technology -- nesting is currently Intel-only.

You will need a different host or a different Hypervisor one that supports nested virtualization on AMD hosts.

Source: [Prerequisites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization#prerequisites)

Comment: This document tells otherwise: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/virtualization/amd-nested-virtualization-support/ba-p/1434841

Comment: @cyberquarks - So are you running an Insider Preview build for Windows 10 version [21H1](https://changewindows.org/milestones/21h1/pc)?

Comment: I only build answers around stabled released versions of Windows 10.  If an question specifically asks about an Insider Preview feature only then will I answer it.  Since your question does not mention using an Insider Preview build of Windows 10, I feel my answer at this time, is accurate.

Comment: @MojoFilter - My answer has a submission date. I don’t make it a habit of updating my answers unless I know they are version specific. The author never indicated they were using an Insider Preview build, therefore, I never updated my answer. My answer is still accurate, per the documentation provided by Microsoft, if that ever changes I will evaluate if it should be updated

Comment: @Ramhound Cool. Still sounds like a pain. I wouldn't have the discipline for it.